# Setting Initial Values In a Dataclass Used in a Mock Before Every Test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

My goal is to write unit tests for a REST API that interfaces with Flash Memory on a device.  To do that, I need a way to mock the class that interfaces with Flash Memory.

I attempted to do that by using a Python Dataclass in the Mock, but I've discovered I do not have any way to set initial values prior to each test.  As a result, each test case is getting values that are set by the previous test case.  I need to fix that.

To test the API, I'm using the following code:

```
@dataclass
class FlashMemoryMock:
    mac_address: str = 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'

@pytest.fixture
def client(mocker):
    mocker.patch('manufacturing_api.bsp.flash_memory.FlashMemory', new=FlashMemoryMock)

    app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='../openapi_server/openapi/')
    app.app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder
    app.add_api('openapi.yaml', pythonic_params=True)

    app.app.config['TESTING'] = True
    with app.app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

def test_get_mac_address(client):
    """Test case for get_mac_address

    Get the MAC Address
    """
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
    response = client.open(
        '/mac_address',
        method='GET',
        headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.is_json
    assert response.json.get('status') == 'success'
    assert response.json.get('mac_address') == 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'
```

This test case will pass because the FlashMemoryMock Dataclass initializes mac_address to `ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`  Unfortunately it would fail if I run it after a `test_put_mac_address` test case if that test changes the mac_address value.

The flash memory controller code looks like this:

```
flash_memory = FlashMemoryWrapper()

def get_mac_address():  # noqa: E501
    return flash_memory.get_mac_address()
```

The FlashMemoryWrapper class validates inputs (i.e. is the user trying to set a valid Mac Address) and includes the following code:

```
class FlashMemoryWrapper:

    def __init__(self):
        # Initialize the Flash controller
        self.flash_memory = FlashMemory()
```

It's this FlashMemory class that I am trying to replace with a Mock.  When I debug the test cases, I have verified FlashMemoryWrapper.flash_memory is referencing FlashMemoryMock.  Unfortunately I no longer have any way to set initial values in the FlashMemoryMock Dataclass.

Is there a way to set initial values?  Or should I set up the Mock a different way?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for can be achieved with a bit of meta-programming in tandem with parametrization of fixtures.

```
def initializer(arg):
    @dataclass
    class FlashMemoryMock:
        mac_address: str = arg
    return FlashMemoryMock


@pytest.fixture
def client(mocker, request):
    mocker.patch('manufacturing_api.bsp.flash_memory.FlashMemory', new=initializer(request.param))

    app = connexion.App(__name__, specification_dir='../openapi_server/openapi/')
    app.app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder
    app.add_api('openapi.yaml', pythonic_params=True)

    app.app.config['TESTING'] = True
    with app.app.test_client() as client:
        yield client

@pytest.mark.parametrize('client', ['ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'], indirect=['client'])
def test_get_mac_address(client):
    """Test case for get_mac_address

    Get the MAC Address
    """
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
    }
    response = client.open(
        '/mac_address',
        method='GET',
        headers=headers)
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.is_json
    assert response.json.get('status') == 'success'
    assert response.json.get('mac_address') == 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff'


# some other test with a different value for mac address
@pytest.mark.parametrize('client', ['ab:cc:dd'], indirect=['client'])
def test_put_mac_address(client):
    # some code here
```

Comment: That is really clever, but unfortunately it did not resolve my issue.  My observation is that the FlashMemoryMock created in the client fixture is not propagated to the server on each test run.  Perhaps I need to do something different to patch the object instead of the class in conjunction with the parameterization above?

Comment: can you elaborate on how it did not work? did the other test functions not get the value that you indicated in the parametrize call?

Comment: If I run a "get" test, I get the value I specify in pytest.mark.parametrize.  Then I run a "put" test to change the value and that works.  If I now run a second "get" test, I get the value that was set by the prior "put" test, not the value I specify in pytest.mark.parametrize.  It appears that the `flash_memory` variable in the flash memory controller is only patched by the mock once.  Then it functions like flash memory!

Comment: are you marking _every_ test with `@pytest.mark.parametrize` and passing in the value that you want for the `mac_address`?

Comment: Yes, I am.  I set the initial value for every test using `@pytest.mark.parametrize`

Comment: it should be patched for every separate test as the fixture by default is function scoped

Comment: Re: "it should be patched for every separate test", what do you mean by that?  Do you mean it should be working like that or that I would need to call mocker.patch in each test case?  I have tried explicitly setting the fixture to have function scope, but I do not observe that behavior.

Comment: That is how it should be working, it would seem that perhaps the fixture is not being torn down if values persist across tests